# Group data in pivot Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hello I made a table with the help of a pandas, then I created a pivot with two indexes., I would like to group this data like that, but one index was the header of another. Below I will show what is happening in the tables and what I would like the result
Table:

| Name | Lang | Skill | Corp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | java | 2 | Google |
| Piter | C++ | 3 | Facebook |
| Cristiano | python | 5 | Google |
| Michael | java | 1 | Facebook |
| Piter | C++ | 2 | Google |
| Cristiano | python | 3 | Facebook |
| Michael | java | 4 | Google |
| Piter | C++ | 5 | Facebook |
| Cristiano | python | 1 | Google |
| Michael | python | 2 | Facebook |

I used:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values="Skill", index=["Corp", "Name"], columns = "Lang", aggfunc="sum")
```

and I have pivot:

| Corp | Name | C++ | java | python |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | Cristiano | nan | nan | 3 |
| Facebook | Michael | nan | 1 | 2 |
| Facebook | Piter | 8 | nan | nan |
| Google | Cristiano | nan | nan | 6 |
| Google | Michael | nan | 6 | nan |
| Google | Piter | 2 | nan | nan |

the result I would like:

| Name | C++ | java | python |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | sum_fb | sum_fb | sum_fb |
| Cristiano | nan | nan | 3 |
| Michael | nan | 1 | 2 |
| Piter | 8 | nan | nan |
| Google | sum_google | sum_google | sum_google |
| Cristiano | nan | nan | 6 |
| Michael | nan | 6 | nan |
| Piter | 2 | nan | nan |

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate sum by `Corp` level, which is first by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), append index to `MultiIndex` with same values:

```
df1 = (pivot.groupby(level=0).sum()
            .assign(Name = lambda x: x.index)
            .set_index('Name', append=True))
```

Or use `level=[0,0]` for MultiIndex, only necessary set names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = pivot.groupby(level=[0,0]).sum().rename_axis(['Corp','Name'])
print (df1)         
Lang               C++  java  python
Corp     Name                       
Facebook Facebook  8.0   1.0     5.0
Google   Google    2.0   6.0     6.0
```

Then is appended `pivot` DataFrame by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), but is necessary sorting for correct ordering by first level of MultiIndex with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), remove first level `Corp` by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) and last convert `Name` to column with remove columns name `Lang` by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, pivot])
        .sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False)
        .droplevel(0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
        Name  C++  java  python
0   Facebook  8.0   1.0     5.0
1  Cristiano  NaN   NaN     3.0
2    Michael  NaN   1.0     2.0
3      Piter  8.0   NaN     NaN
4     Google  2.0   6.0     6.0
5  Cristiano  NaN   NaN     6.0
6    Michael  NaN   6.0     NaN
7      Piter  2.0   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: It works as I would like, Thank you! Could you explain what's going on here or give me material where can i read about it? because I'm learning

Comment: @Abradab3 - Answer was edited.

Comment: thank you! I have another problem, I added the "All" column. I would like to sort this Corp groups. In this example Google and Facebook are All = 14, but if I get groups: Facebook 15 Google 12 ASW: 10. How can I sort these groups and take only the two with the highest values ​​"all"

Comment: @Abradab3 I am offline, on phone only, the beat post new question.